# Probability that the difference of two integers, chosen randomly, is 15

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Question:** If two different integers between $1$ and $100$ are chosen at random, what is the probability that the difference of the two numbers is $15$?

Comment: What do you mean?  If your two numbers are $a,b$, you just want $|a-b|=15$.  Thus the pair $(50,65)$ works, for example.

Comment: If the problem is meant in absolute value, then for every number picked first there are 2 numbers that can be picked to have difference 15, except in the case where the first is >85 or <16, in which case you have only one. So the probability is $70/100\times 2/100+ 30/100\times 1/100= 17/1000.$

Comment: @RiccardoCeccon  Not quite...as the two choices are required to be distinct, you should have $\frac 2{99},\frac 1{99}$ as your second factors.  Though I think it is easier to work with unordered pairs...there are $85$ such which differ by $15$ and $\binom {100}2$ such in total.

Comment: My bad, didn't get that they're different

Comment: @lulu that I know..I worded my question the wrong way..I know that in order for the difference of two numbers to be $15$ that $|a-b|=15$. How do we use this fact to derive this probability question?

Comment: Well, the method from @RiccardoCeccon  works perfectly (once you correct for the small error I mentioned).  As I mentioned in an earlier comment, I would favor a different approach...since each unordered pair is equally probable we can count the "winners" by counting the possible lower term.  The lower term can be any of $\{1,2,\cdots, 85\}$.  Of course $86$ or greater fails since $86+15>100$.  Thus there are exactly $85$ winners, and as there are $\binom {100}2$ unordered pairs with no restrictions...

Comment: how does $86$ or greater fail if $86-71=15$? would you be able to expand your answer more by stating your entire approach below @lulu

Comment: In the unordered pair $\{71,86\}$ the least element is $71$ so I get that pair starting from $71$.  I'm just counting the unordered pairs that differ by $15$.  To do so, I remark that the least element in any such pair must be between $1$ and $85$ (inclusive) and that any such number gives rise to exactly one unordered pair of which it is the least member.

Comment: To be more literal:  the unordered pairs that differ by $15$ are precisely $\{1,16\},\{2,17\},\cdots, \{85,100\}$  and it is obvious that there are $85$ such pairs.

Comment: @lulu okay i understand up to that point, how do we change this 85 such pairs into a probability?

Comment: would the probability be $\frac{85}{100}$? @lulu

Comment: No.  There are $85$ unordered pairs that work, and $\binom {100}2$ ordered pairs in total.

Comment: okay.....so how do i find the probability that the difference between the two numbers is 15 using this fact

Comment: Please put some effort of your own into this. The solution from @RiccardoCeccon is complete, except for the small error I pointed out already.  And my hints really amount to a complete solution.

Comment: im trying to understand where he got his numbers from, the $\frac{70}{100} \times \frac{2}{100} +\frac{3}{100} \times \frac{1}{100}$ @RiccardoCeccon

Comment: @rover2 actually the reasoning is this: in $70$ cases out of $100,$ which are the cases where the first number lies between $16$ and $85$ (both included), there are $2$ possibilities out of $99$ (I know it is different from what I told before, but I didn't see that the numbers had to be different) that the other number is distant from the first by $15.$ In the other $30$ cases out of $100$ there is just $1$ possibilities out of $99$ that the other number is distant by $15.$ For example, if the first number is $92,$ just the second number $77$ will be good because $107$ is not extractible.